# Does a function that has an exponential analog to $log(xy) = log(x) + log(y)$ exist?

Tags: calculus, special-functions

Similar to how $log(xy) = log(x) + log(y)$, does a nontrivial function exist that has the property $f(x^y) = f(x)f(y)$? How would one attempt to derive such a function?

Comment: I don't understand the analogy here?

Comment: @copper.hat I guess the idea is to replace multiplication with exponentiation and addition with multiplication.

Comment: Exponentiation is not analogous to multiplication. The latter is symmetrical algebraic operation, the former is not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Then $f(x^y) = f(y^x) \Rightarrow f(1^y) = f(y^1) \Rightarrow f(1) = f(y)$ for any $y$. f is a constant function, $0$ or $1$.

Comment: You missed an $f$.

Comment: Just a little typo: cons${\Large\bf\mbox{t}}$ant. It's a fine proof. UpVote $0$ k.

Comment: Oh, two typos in one sentence :)